# EditorFor passes value to POST controller in viewModel, but DisplayFor and HiddenFor don't?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my view I have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Contact, new{style="width: 650px"})
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Backflip()
        {
            // TODO: Make sure name is what we expect
            var contact = getContact();
            return View(new BackflipViewModel(contact));
        }

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Broadcast(BackflipViewModel vm)
    {...
```

viewModel:

```
public class BackflipViewModel
{

    public BackflipViewModel()
    {
    }

    public BackflipViewModel(Contact contact)
    {
        Sender = contact;
    }

    public Contact Sender { get; set; }

}
```

I really just want a hiddenFor, but if I try @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Sender), "vm" in my POST controller method contains a null value for Sender.  Same for DisplayFor.  How can I get HiddenFor working?

Comment: `DisplayFor` does not write out an input element, so its values won't be in the POST. That's not its purpose. As for the `HiddenFor`, does `Model.Sender` definitely have a value? Can you check that the hidden field is rendered out in your markup (in-browser) and whether it has a value?

Comment: Ah, ok.  I just checked and it is rendering Sender when I use HiddenFor.  vm does contain other properties that have EditorFor(), but  vm.Sender is null.

Comment: @AntP - response above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `HiddenFor` - unlike `EditorFor` - is not capable of producing an entire set of fields for a complex object.

You should do something like the following, instead.

**View Model**

```
public string SenderId { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SenderId)
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Broadcast(BackflipViewModel vm)
{
    If (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Sender sender = getContact(Model.SenderId);
    }
}
```